# Issue with SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldatareader

I am using a `SqlDataReader` and while trying to read the reader I am having rows.

When I check `.HasRows`, the rows are not available.

```
List<EmployeeTimings> empTimingsList = new List<EmployeeTimings>();

// Creates a SQL connection
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WINPAKContext"].ToString()))
{
    // Creates a SQL command
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SEED_VIEW WHERE empid is not null and DateTime > '" + dtlastpunch + "' order by datetime", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        // Loads the query results into the table
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                EmployeeTimings empTime = new EmployeeTimings();
                empTime.CardNumber = reader["CardNO"].ToString();
                empTime.EMPId = reader["EMPID"].ToString();
                empTime.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                empTime.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                empTime.Location = reader["Location"].ToString();
                empTime.Trans_DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateTime"]);

                empTimingsList.Add(empTime);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    connection.Close();
}

return empTimingsList;
```

Could you please let me know whats the issue?

What's happening after `reader.HasRows()` call, the redaer does not have any rows....

Comment: What is that `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` call towards the end of your code?? Totally pointless - you've **already** executed the SQL statement and read in all the rows returned from it......

Answer (score 5):

there is no need to check HasRow property just Read is enough, if you use just read method and try to read row from reader which is not having any row than it will just exist while loop

you can write like , remove hasRow there is no need of it

```
while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                EmployeeTimings empTime = new EmployeeTimings();
                                empTime.CardNumber = reader["CardNO"].ToString();
                                empTime.EMPId = reader["EMPID"].ToString();
                                empTime.FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                                empTime.LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();
                                empTime.Location = reader["Location"].ToString();
                                empTime.Trans_DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DateTime"]);
                                empTimingsList.Add(empTime);
                            }
```

**Avoid SQLInjection**

apart form this your code will allow SQLInjection as you are directly passing value in query...Make use of parameterize query rather than code like this.

**Issue with datetime condition in query**

There might be issue as you are comparing datetime value in where condition without applying any conversion. This issue will get resolve if you use parameterized sql query.

Comment: I found the issue That I am looking the reader in debugger window

Comment: @AJAYcHIGURUPATI - ok but I recommend you should avoid sql injection and for that use parameterized query....

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatablereader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - your code looks good. Try to investigate returned sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove entire wrapping block

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
...
}
```

Your code will keep the same functionality and you do not have to bother about the HasRows :)

one more comment. please remove the following line in your code:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: No I am facing one more issue while deploying to Server.     "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."